# Google certificate does not match private key in Play console

Tags: android, certificate, bundle, google-play-console

I was about to publish my first app on Play Store and everything ran smooth until I had to upload my Android Studio Bundle encrypted key (.pepk file).
The Play console displays the following error message :
"The private key does not match the certificate we have for this application". (english translation of a french message).
I do not know what to do. I downloaded and ran the pepk java tool but the result is the same.
What is the certificate the console is talking about ?
Is it possible to reset it and how ?
When I tried to upload a "regular" apk file, the console blocked and forced me to build my app as a Android App Bundle, thus requiring a .pepk file for the encrypted private key.

I have never changed my email for perhaps 20 years. I only bought a new laptop tow months ago.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution for this?